# How to implement secure FTP connection on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, sftp, cfnetwork

Apple provide a CFNetwork guide, where described how to work with FTP. I interested to work with SFTP. Everywhere chilkat ftp library is suggested, but he has a too big feature list, that is unnecessary to pay.
Are there any way to connect to SFTP only for download, upload and viewing directory lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP is just an extension of the SSH protocol. I would look for an open source SSH library, such as [this one](http://www.libssh.org/). Most have support for the SFTP protocol.

One thing to note, if you intend to use it in an App Store app, you may want to remove the server capability from the library, as Apple probably wouldn't allow it. If, by some slight chance, the library even builds and runs with the SSH server capability, you may be able to get it into the App Store if you don't enable the server.

Of course, I'm sure there are libraries out there with client-only capabilities if removing server support yourself doesn't sound all that dandy.

Answer (score 2):

/n software IP*Works! SSH for iOS (www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssh/) is another commercial solution. It includes an SFTP library as well as a number of other iOS communications libraries.